# What does a C process status mean in htop?

Tags: macos, htop

I am using htop on osx and I can't seem to find out what a 'C' status in the 'S' status column means for a process status.

What does a C process status mean in htop?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

htop author here. I am not aware of such status code in the htop codebase. 
Keep in mind that htop is written for Linux only, so there is no support for macOS/OSX. When I hear of people running it on OSX they are often using an outdated, unsupported fork (the latest version of htop is 2.0.1, including macOS support).

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 69):

Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

- **D** Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
- **R** Running or runnable (on run queue)
- **S** Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
- **T** Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
- **W** Paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
- **X** Dead (should never be seen)
- **Z** Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.

**Source: [`man ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)**

I recently came across a second list:

- **R**  Running
- **S**  Sleeping in an interruptible wait
- **D**  Waiting in uninterruptible disk sleep
- **Z**  Zombie
- **T**  Stopped (on a signal) or (before Linux 2.6.33) trace stopped
- **t**  Tracing stop (Linux 2.6.33 onward)
- **W**  Paging (only before Linux 2.6.0)
- **X**  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)
- **x**  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
- **K**  Wakekill (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
- **W**  Waking (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
- **P**  Parked (Linux 3.9 to 3.13 only)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html in the "/proc/[pid]/stat" section:

Answer (score 20):

I've got the same question recently. We can try to look it up in the [htop sources](https://github.com/max-horvath/htop-osx/blob/master/ProcessList.c#L726):

```
process->state =
    ProcessList_decodeState( p->p_stat == SZOMB ? SZOMB : ki->state );

static int
ProcessList_decodeState( int st ) {
  switch ( st ) {
  case SIDL:
    return 'C';
  case SRUN:
    return 'R';
  case SSLEEP:
    return 'S';
  case SSTOP:
    return 'T';
  case SZOMB:
    return 'Z';
  default:
    return '?';
  }
}
```

So we go to Unix definition of process states at /usr/include/sys/proc.h:

```
/* Status values. */
#define SIDL    1       /* Process being created by fork. */
#define SRUN    2       /* Currently runnable. */
#define SSLEEP  3       /* Sleeping on an address. */
#define SSTOP   4       /* Process debugging or suspension. */
#define SZOMB   5       /* Awaiting collection by parent. */
```

So, 'C' status is meant to be 'Process being created by fork'. What is it? According to [old unix sources](http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/u6ed/usr/sys/ken/slp.c.html#n:428), it's a transient state that happens when there's not enough memory when forking a process and the parent needs to be swapped out.

What??

Back to htop source. Where do we get the `ki->state`?

```
// For all threads in process:
error = thread_info( ki->thread_list[j], THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
                     ( thread_info_t ) & ki->thval[j].tb,
                     &thread_info_count );

tstate = ProcessList_machStateOrder( ki->thval[j].tb.run_state,
                                     ki->thval[j].tb.sleep_time );
if ( tstate < ki->state )
  ki->state = tstate;

// Below...
static int
ProcessList_machStateOrder( int s, long sleep_time ) {
  switch ( s ) {
  case TH_STATE_RUNNING:
    return 1;
  case TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE:
    return 2;
  case TH_STATE_WAITING:
    return ( sleep_time > 20 ) ? 4 : 3;
  case TH_STATE_STOPPED:
    return 5;
  case TH_STATE_HALTED:
    return 6;
  default:
    return 7;
  }
}

// In mach/thread_info.h: 
#define TH_STATE_RUNNING  1 /* thread is running normally */
#define TH_STATE_STOPPED  2 /* thread is stopped */
#define TH_STATE_WAITING  3 /* thread is waiting normally */
#define TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE 4  /* thread is in an uninterruptible wait */
#define TH_STATE_HALTED   5 /* thread is halted at a clean point */
```

We have the following (messed up) mapping:

```
Thread state             | Mapped to | htop state| 'top' state | 'ps' state
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TH_STATE_RUNNING         | SIDL(1)   |       'C' | running     | 'R'
TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE | SRUN(2)   |       'R' | stuck       | 'U'
TH_STATE_WAITING (short) | SSLEEP(3) |       'S' | sleeping    | 'S'
TH_STATE_WAITING (long)  | SSTOP(4)  |       'T' | idle        | 'I'
TH_STATE_STOPPED         | SZOMB(5)  |       'Z' | stopped     | 'T'
```

So, the real answer is: **'C' means that the process is currently running.**

How did it happen? Seems that the `ki->state` handling was borrowed from [`ps` source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-149/ps/tasks.c) and wasn't adjusted for Unix process codes.

Update: this [bug is fixed](https://github.com/max-horvath/htop-osx/pull/12). Yay open source!