# in linux - show a list of all processes and note if they are running or suspended

Tags: linux

I'm new to linux.

How can I show a list of all processes that says about each process if it's running or suspended? 
 I've tried

```
ps -ef|grep myusername
```

but it doesn't say if the processes are running or not.
also tried

```
ps ux
```

same thing, it doesn't say if the processes are running or not.

I'm looking for something like this list: 
[I get this list when I move a process to background, I don't know how to see it otherwise...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCVn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use "ps" to list processes, This (ps aux) will list all the processes. Given an example output of it below.**

ps aux | more

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND 

root         1  0.0  0.1 189160  9376 ?        Ss   15:51   0:04 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 20

root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:51   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:51   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   15:51   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:51   0:06 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:51   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:51   0:04 [rcuos/0]
```

By checking the STAT of the process ( UNDER "STAT" ) you can identify the process states, Below are some possible states codes.

- R  running or runnable (on run queue)
- D  uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
- S  interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
- Z  defunct/zombie, terminated but not reaped by its parent
- T  stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being
  traced

You can type "man ps" to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htop to see the list of processes and there is a column for process state

[What does a C process status mean in htop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470215/what-does-a-c-process-status-mean-in-htop)

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

**ps -p PID -o comm=**

Enter the code above where PID is PID of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Following command will be more helpful to you.

Use the command : `sudo lsof -i -n -P`

This command lists the Application Name, PID, User, IP version, Device ID and the Node with Port Name. It shows both TCP and UDP.

Variations :

To format it in a nice, readable way; use :

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | more
```

To view view only TCP connections :

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | more
```

To view view only UDP connections :

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep UDP | more
```